# WakeConditionVariable() vs WakeAllConditionVariable() performance

Tags: c++, performance, winapi, synchronization, condition-variable

There is a situation in which both `WakeConditionVariable()` and `WakeAllConditionVariable()` can be used to wake up. There is anyway no more than 1 thread waiting.
Is any of these functions faster?

Comment: WakeConditionVariable is bit faster but when several threads wait on same variable. but even in this case different in performance very-very low. in case when only one thread wait on conditional variable - at all no difference